# How can I wrap content in both directions 2 views to best use parent space

Tags: android

I have a Linear Layout that has 2 buttons(not really, this is just a simplified version), I want the 2 buttons to have the same height but different widths so that they use as little space as possible.Like this:

Good:

[image]

Bad(lots of free space in button 2):

[image]

This is of course a bit unfortunate because android does not seem to wrap very well in both directions.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="Rar riego todune ieyed nili rilo noledo oso ilow. Resulieh hi itepitep. Nena pis te osur uporeta, vef rilan te ege enono vesanep re caba? Hirica bugus le relam liri delira. Naneva recimen te netegar tic anote sul ese da; sie pihic lasimiw rife nepime ediyira mic eja hos. Kinir ragovo orero gegol haroy di nacecid cotam anana idom. Cienad keti cu. Tano nosaroh hu yih; reheh ratasu iwayag cuc detiwo elalir irerun, ero iyuluv pe pumip atage dono epam secehag re nineq. Gisi upur yogeget tikige. Ka etex ateyusip tetediey ke nina irahi nirayo nimidor! Nuda de racur pas. Cof nurar mije ron nom saxuv. Sepuno so ner, pa fakun laki le som." />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="Mebieron hina ciras risa ne, neno telonup edinieba irara we eyacarob til re lum guyiga. Sagiko rubana tit rula gun sisan. Hil romiene to pute sip tuyud risomim etasi vicaro, tedoc te coke rel arietota epa masisir nenacec, gorula fol anu sep rie. Har vipahier metodo siebegu ival are ureh dodor rorel. " />
</LinearLayout>
```

What I have noticed up until now:

1 I need the Linear Layout to have WMP(width match parent) and HWC(height wrap content).

2 Button WMP+HMP(both because button1 should be symmetrical to button2) or WMP+HWC forces the other button out of the screen(and in a weird way its height to maxout the screen, making view after the LL to not appear, because the LL thinks it needs the whole screen, unless you have a scrollable layout and then the LL will expand to the height of each word summed and then display the rest of the content. If the second button has only 1 word the LL will not expand like crazy).

3 WWC+HWC same scenario as above but only if text is big/multiline, if text is small then they are ok.

4 WWC+HMP same scenario except now the first button is as big as the screen.

5 If I use layout_weight the 2 buttons use 50-50 of the screen and if one of the buttons has 2x more text the other button has a huge amount of whitespace.

6 Grid layout behaves just like linear layout

Comment: sometimes one image tells more than 6 items. hard figure out the problem with so much explanations

Comment: @uguboz my appologies

Comment: So you are arranging them horizontally! or vertically? What do you want!

Comment: @Xenolion horizontally, they are in a horizontal linear layout

Comment: Honestly I dont understand the question send a picture, of how you want them to be!

Comment: @Xenolion are these 2 picture good?

Comment: why don't u align the text to top. it is easy and more readable. let the space remain below. otherwise u need custom button and too many text calculation

Comment: Hey I answered your question 13hours ago! I am sure it works! Try 
and give me a response,if works accept my answer and vote up! @ThenEnok

Comment: @uguboz that would only move the whitespace to the bottom, what I was hoping for is to use as few as possible

Comment: @Xenolion I appreciate your enthusiasm, but I did not dispose of any free time today to continue working on the subject

Comment: Ooh good to know!, We are together! @ThenEnok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I tried to find if there are any default implementation of that in android default views but there no XML attribute to use for that, even in `TableLayout` although we can make a simple formula to calculate that and give yours views similar height without care about the width!

Here is how:
In your class declare member variables of the views of interest!

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private LinearLayout linearLayout;
        private Button btn_one;
        private Button btn_two;
```

Then in the `onCreate` method, after `setContentView()`  get the views by id for example

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          linearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
          btn_one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_one);
          btn_two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_two);
```

After that here comes the most important part! We need to find the width of the linear layout before we know how to divide it to the buttons.But we cant use the width by calling `linearLayout.getWidth()` because we are in `onCreate()` and the linear layout may have not been created yet and the method will return zero. So in the `onCreate()` we are going to use a `Runnable` that will give us a confirmation that the `linearLayout` is made and so it will run.

In `onCreate()` add the code:

```
    linearLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           balanceHeight(btn_one,btn_two);
        }
    });
}
```

`balanceHeight` is the method that we are going to use to divide our width so as to balance Height.
Outside your `onCreate()`but inside your activity class copy the following code!:

```
    private void balanceHeight(Button btn_one, Button btn_two) {
    int length1 = btn_one.getText().length();
    int length2 = btn_two.getText().length();
    int total = length1+length2;

    int total_width=linearLayout.getWidth();

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int)(((float)length1/(float)total)*(float) total_width), ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int)(((float)length2/(float)total)*(float) total_width), ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    btn_one.setLayoutParams(params1);
    btn_two.setLayoutParams(params2);

}
```

This method accept Two buttons as parameters and get their text length compare them and use the linear layout width to divide it according to their content and available space. I have casted values to float to improve accuracy.

**Note:** When importing layout params class make sure its `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`every root views has `.LayoutParams` so make sure you import the right one.
Also if you real want button you can continue using it. But in Android any View is clickable if you real want a button do it, but if not use a TextView and set OnClickListener to it!

Comment: Not was I expecting, but great nonetheless (I was expecting some way of overwriting how android calculated the view sizes before the wrapping)

Comment: Ooh I never thought of that, There has be another alternative and if overwriting or extending layouts classes when views are created step by step, then its obvious that it will be more efficient because my solution updates the already created view!

Comment: Great nonetheless.